# spark-submit: turning on 'recursive' (Spark version 2.0.2)

Tags: apache-spark

I'm attempting to specify a directory as an argument to --files in `spark-submit`.   The job fails with the message:

```
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Added file file:[directory path] is a directory and recursive is not turned on.
```

There is nothing in `spark-submit --help` about specifying recursive, and Googling around didn't show it either.  Anyone know about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This relates to [SPARK-16408](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-16408). The error is thrown at [this line](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/SparkContext.scala#L1537) because spark-submit calls `addFile` with recursive set to false per default.

As a workaround you should specify each file separately or call `addFile` on your SparkContext object at runtime with recursive set to true

```
sc.addFile(path = ..., recursive = true)
```